# angularfire 2 error: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'firestore'

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

Getting this error while trying to add firebase into my Angular5 application. How can I remove this error?

I have tried to downgrade the version of firebase but it causes some more errors.

Comment: Share how you import files i don't have any problem in angular5 with firestore

Comment: import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

Comment: Now getting more errors.       D:\angular5\firstApp\src\firebase\firestore doesn't exist

Comment: turn off ng serve do npm command from answer and start again ng serve

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2'; 
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

this is my setup also npm install angularfire2 firebase --save if you forgot

Check docs on [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)

This is from docs `imports firebase/firestore` only needed for database features.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hctqdy check this...firestore is missing here ..file is collection.d.ts and the link is to app.d.ts